# Unable to remove snap package "slack"

Tags: ubuntu, slack, snap

Slack stopped working so I decided to remove it with snap and then install it again. Removing failed, after trying a few times I now get the following output:

```
$ sudo snap remove slack
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Remove snap "slack" (63) from the system (cannot parse systemctl output: "Bus n/a: changing state UNSET → OPENING")
```

Some more snap output:

```
$ slack list
slack                    -                           63     latest/stable    slack✓       disabled,broken
```

...

```
$ snap changes
ID   Status  Spawn                Ready                Summary
474  Error   today at 11:52 CEST  today at 11:59 CEST  Remove "slack" snap
475  Error   today at 11:59 CEST  today at 11:59 CEST  Remove "slack" snap
476  Error   today at 12:01 CEST  today at 12:01 CEST  Remove "slack" snap
477  Error   today at 12:02 CEST  today at 12:02 CEST  Remove "slack" snap
478  Error   today at 12:04 CEST  today at 12:04 CEST  Remove "slack" snap
479  Error   today at 12:05 CEST  today at 12:05 CEST  Remove "slack" snap
480  Error   today at 12:07 CEST  today at 12:07 CEST  Enable "slack" snap
481  Error   today at 12:11 CEST  today at 12:11 CEST  Remove "slack" snap
482  Error   today at 12:11 CEST  today at 12:11 CEST  Remove "slack" snap
483  Error   today at 12:11 CEST  today at 12:11 CEST  Remove "slack" snap
484  Error   today at 12:35 CEST  today at 12:35 CEST  Remove "slack" snap
```

...

```
$ uname -a
Linux systemname 5.13.0-51-generic #58~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 14 11:29:12 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```